# Why does n need to be positive

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

in k&r c, 2nd edition, page 59:

```
/* itoa: convert n to characters in s */
void itoa(int n, char s[])
{
    int i, sign;
    if ((sign = n) < 0) /* record sign */
        n = -n;         /* make n positive --- why need this? */ 
    i = 0;
    do
    {                          /* generate digits in reverse order */
        s[i++] = n % 10 + '0'; /* get next digit */
    } while ((n /= 10) > 0);   /* delete it */
    if (sign < 0)
        s[i++] = '-';
    s[i] = '\0';
    reverse(s);
}
```

Why does n need to be positive, is this needed in c++?

Comment: When `n` will not be flipped to a positive number, the `while` condition `(n /= 10) > 0` will be `false` immediately.

Answer (score 2):

This function from the book is quite bad.

`n = -n` will invoke undefined behaviour (UB) if `n` is equal to INT_MIN.

> Why does n need to be positive, is this needed in c++?

In C++ doing it this way will produce the wrong result for INT_MIN.

It is good to return the pointer to the converted string. It allows you to use the result of this function in expressions or as a parameter of other functions.

`n % 10 + '0'` is not very portable. It is better to use table with digits. It will work with **any** character encoding.

Another problem: do not use the names of the standard library functions.

K&R IMO is a bit outdated and many programming techniques are considered bad nowadays.

```
char *reverse(char *s)
{
    char *wrk = s, *end = s;
    if(s && *s)
    {
        while(*(end + 1)) end++;
        while(end > wrk)
        {
            char tmp = *wrk;
            *wrk++ = *end;
            *end-- = tmp;
        } 
    }
    return s;
}

char *myitoa(int n, char s[])
{
    static const char digits[]="0123456789";
    int sign = n < 0;
    char *wrk = s;
    do
    {
        *wrk++ = digits[abs(n % 10)];
        n /= 10;
    }while(n);
    if(sign) *wrk++ = '-';
    *wrk = 0;
    reverse(s);
    return s;
}

int main(void)
{
    char buff[64];
    printf("%s\n", myitoa(INT_MIN, buff));
    printf("%s\n", myitoa(INT_MAX, buff));
    printf("%s\n", myitoa(0, buff));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/5so8chvcn

Comment: Nobody cares about other encodings, and even EBCDIC has digits adjacent (though not letters).

Comment: @o11c some people do.

Comment: *`n* % 10 + '0'` is not very portable.*  [Wrong.](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.1p3)  This is guaranteed to produce the lowest-order digit of `n` in any encoding.

Comment: @AndrewHenle it only says that the character set has to have digits from `0` to `9` but does not say anything about the order or codes.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Can you point me to the sentence where the standard says that digits have to have consecutive codes and have to be ordered from 0 to 9?

Comment: @0___________ "In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous."

Answer (score 0):

The function aims to convert an integer into an array of characters.  What is the difference between converting `123` and `-123` into characters?  Well, nothing really, aside from the negative sign.  So, this implementation of `itoa()` basically stores the sign and then operates on the digits themselves, since those are the main sources of information.  At the end, if the sign was negative, the function appends the `-` character to the array and then finally reverses it.